# On the use of \titleofcontents to customize the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc

I use the following piece of code (titletoc package) to customize the "part entries" of my table of contents. Can you help me to push the page number to the right so that it is aligned with the other page numbers?

```
\titlecontents{part}[0pt]{
\protect\addvspace{15pt}%
}{}{\large\bfseries\partname{} }{$\;$\titlerule$\;$\large\bfseries\thecontentspage}[]
```

[image]

---

**Complete working example**

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titlecontents{part}[0pt]{
\protect\addvspace{15pt}%
}{}{\large\bfseries\partname{} }{$\;$\titlerule$\;$\large\bfseries\thecontentspage}[]

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Part 1}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Section 1.1}
\section{Section 1.2}
\chapter{Chapter 2}
\section{Section 2.1}
\section{Section 2.2}
\part{Part 2}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Section 1.1}
\section{Section 1.2}
\chapter{Chapter 2}
\section{Section 2.1}
\section{Section 2.2}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is that what you want? Your code didn't reset chapter numbers at each new part, so I used the `chngcntr`  package.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin*{chapter}{part}

\titlecontents{part}[0pt]{\large\bfseries\protect\addvspace{15pt}}%
{}{\partname{}}%
{\enspace\titlerule \contentspage}%

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Part One}

\chapter{Chapter the First}
\section{Section 1.1}
\section{Section 1.2}

\chapter{Chapter the Second}
\section{Section 2.1}
\section{Section 2.2}

\part{Part Two}

\chapter{Chapter the First}
\section{Section 1.1}
\section{Section 1.2}

\chapter{Chapter the Second}
\section{Section 2.1}
\section{Section 2.2}

\end{document}
```

[image]